# Angular: 12 - Cannot access 'AppComponent' before initialization when doing "ng test"

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

When I'm trying to run "ng test", I just getting like the below:

**Error message in UI by Karma v 6.3.4**:
0 specs, 0 failures, randomized with seed 98146 Error during loading: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'AppComponent' before initialization in http://localhost:9876/karma_webpack/main.js line 125

**Error message in terminal**:
An error was thrown in afterAll Uncaught ReferenceError: **Cannot access 'AppComponent' before initialization** ReferenceError: Cannot access 'AppComponent' before initialization at Module.AppComponent (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/main.js:125:61) at Module.36747 (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/**app.module.ts:16:5**)

**App.module TS FILE**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgxUiLoaderModule } from 'ngx-ui-loader';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpConfigInterceptor } from './auth/httpconfig.interceptor';
import { HeaderModule } from './shared/header/header.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.serviceWorker, registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately' }),
    NgxUiLoaderModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HeaderModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AppComponent,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpConfigInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

Is anyone knows how we can solve this?

Comment: I encountered this error when moving from 11 to 13. https://github.com/angular/components/issues/23907

Answer (score 1):

> When I'm trying to run "ng test", I just getting like the below:

You have a test file ending with "spec.ts" which is mis-configured and that is causing this error. Check browser developer options and find out that meddling `*spec.ts`. After that you've two options:

- delete that test file if you don't plan to test or
- add required `modules`, `providers`, ... in your `TestBed.configureTestingModule(...)`, so that spec.ts file is able to build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to remove the `AppComponent` from the `providers` array. That can cause the error you are encountering.

Comment: I've tried to do this and still having the same error.
**app.module.ts:16:5**, **line 16** refers to AppComponent in the **declarations** array

Comment: Nonetheless, you should not put it in the providers array. That's a component, and components should be in the `declarations` array.